# How to get error page with user entered parameter or page name in php

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, parameters

I didn't get a proper solution for this issue.  the URL should be like

http://mydomain.com/poem/**xyz**

here I need to process the the value **xyz** in http://mydomain.com/poem/index.php, and accordingly I need to take some actions.

Is it possible with php or through jquery?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a mod_rewrite rule that redirects all request to this directory structure to your index.php and sends you the mentioned part of the URL as a GET variable to the script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct this can be done by sending a GET request. GET requests send data via the URL and can be picked up with PHP.

to pass data via the url you can set a link like this

`<a href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page_id=2"> Page Link </a>`
Anything after the question mark will be passed over. To send more than 1 value use

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?page_id=2&search=string
```

now you can use some PHP in index.php to pick up your passed variable via GET request using

```
<?php 

    $_GET['page_id'];
    $_GET['search']; 

?>
```

and from here you can perform conditional statements etc...

```
<?php if($_GET['page_id'] == 2)

    echo "2nd Page ID...";

?>
```

You can also check to see if a $_GET[] variable has been set using

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_GET['page_id'])) {

         echo "page id has been set to".$_GET['page_id'];

      } else echo "Page id has not been set";

?>
```

Comment: Please take the time to let me know why the -1 seeing as I took the time to try and answer

Comment: Its not like that, if **//www.mysite.com/** this is my domain, an user trying to browse something like **//www.mysite.com/admin** then it will display 404 error, right, but I need to take the word 'admin' from the url and process it some other page. this actually I need.

Comment: @JustAPirate I dont want to redirects all the requests, anyway I didnt try it, let me try.

Comment: Could you not just use some php to grab the url?